# (ngModel) not reflecting in change event handler

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

In my application developed using Angular 2, on selection of a dropdown the ngModel does update the variable declared in the component but the value does not reflect in the "change" event handler of the dropdown.

Here is the concerning HTML code.

```html
<div class="modal-body">
                <form #wallForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save()" class="wallForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <span class="sr-only">Select Wall and Board</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        {{selectedWall.Id}}
                        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedWall.Id" name="Wall" (change)="wallSelected()">
                            <option *ngFor="let wall of walls" value={{wall.Id}}>{{wall.Item.Title}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">

                                class="btn active-element btn-lg width-50" *ngIf="itemAction == '0'">
                            Copy
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" (click)="save()"
                                class="btn active-element btn-lg width-50" *ngIf="itemAction == '1'">
                            Move
                        </button>                        
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
```

Here is the typescript.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
//import { MODAL_DIRECTIVES, BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS } from 'js/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';


@Component({
    selector: 'movecopy-item',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/forms/componentManagement/movecopyForm.component.html'
})

export class movecopyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('mcFormModal') modal: ModalDirective;
    private currentUser: user;
    private itemAction: ITEM_ACTION;
    private modalTitle: string;

    @Input() component: viewItem;
    walls: viewItem[];
    selectedWall: viewItem;

    constructor(private _contentService: ContentService,
        private _alertService: AlertService,
        private _router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //Get all the walls for the user.
        this.walls = [];
        this.selectedWall = new viewItem();
        this.loadWalls();
    }

    private loadWalls() {
        this._contentService.getAllWalls()
            .subscribe(data => this.wallListReceived(data),
            error => this.handleError(error));
    }

    private wallListReceived(data: any) {
        this.walls = data;
    }

    hide() {
        this.modal.hide();
    }

    private wallSelected(): void {
        console.log('Selected wall');
        console.log(this.selectedWall.Id);
        //get boards for the wall. 
        this.getWallContent();
        console.log(this.selectedWall.Id);
    }
```

The `{{selectedWall.Id}}` does get updated, but for some reason in the `wallSelected` method, `this.selectedWall.Id` keeps returning a 0.

What am I doing wrong here? What might be the reason for the value not reflecting here?

Comment: I assume you meant `change` instead of `click` in the questions title. `click` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes I am sorry. I did indeed mean change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of events on an element is undefined. You can't expect `ngModel` to update the model before the event handler for the `change` event was processed.

Use instead

```
(ngModelChange)="wallSelected()"
```

because `ngModel` only emits `ngModelChange` after it updated the model